# How to tell Java to use jline3

Tags: scala, sbt, jline

Scala newbie and following [this](http://tpolecat.github.io/2014/12/12/getting-started.html) blog to use `sbt` (I have a little Java experience using Eclipse).

`sbt` is working, however I must have the `ncurses` issue described [here](https://github.com/jline/jline2/issues/281). Instead of downgrading `ncurses` I'm trying to upgrade `jline`.
I cloned the new `jline3` repo and installed it using `mvn`.

I don't know how to point `java` to use the new `jline3`. Which is the same as saying, "I don't know how to fix this problem with scala / sbt".

- OS: Arch: Manjaro
- ncurses Version : 6.0+20170902-1
- java -version
- openjdk version "1.8.0_144"
- OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)

Comment: Do you mean add jline3 as a library? You can do this by creating a new folder named 'lib' in the project's root directory and put the jline3 jar into the folder.The lib folder is sbt's default unmanaged library directory.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. I was thinking in terms of making all of Java use jline3 which is dumb, b/c only this project needs it.

Comment: The error I get comes when I run `sbt`. I don't think the `lib` directory is being seen at that point.